# Bower dependency tilde in Node

Tags: javascript, bower

In bower (a node dependency package manager), on some dependencies the version is preceded by a tilde.  What does this mean?

```
{
    "name": "mean",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "3.0.0",
        "angular": "~1.0.6"
    }
{
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> ~1.2.3 := >=1.2.3-0 <1.3.0-0 "Reasonably close to 1.2.3". When using
>   tilde operators, prerelease versions are supported as well, but a
>   prerelease of the next significant digit will NOT be satisfactory, so
>   1.3.0-beta will not satisfy ~1.2.3.

From the documentation of the underlying [semver](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver)